# Programmatically create bash command with flags for items in array

Tags: bash

I have a list/array like so:

```
['path/to/folder/a', 'path/to/folder/b']
```

This is an example, the array can be of any length. But for each item in the array I'd like to set up the following as a single command:

```
$ someTool <command> --flag <item-1> --flag <item-2> ... --flag <item-N>
```

At the moment I am currently doing a loop over the array but I am just wondering if doing them individually has a different behaviour to doing them all at once (which the tool specifies I should do).

```
for i in "${array[@]}"; do
 someTool command --flag $i
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether passing all flag arguments to a single invocation of the tool does the same thing as passing them one-at-a-time to separate invocations depends entirely on the tool and what it does. Without more information, it's impossible to say for sure, but if the instructions recommend passing them all at once, I'd go with that.

The simplest way to do this in bash is generally to create a second array with the flags *and* arguments as they need to be passed to the tool:

```
flagsArray=()
for i in "${array[@]}"; do
    flagsArray+=(--flag "$i")
done
someTool command "${flagsArray[@]}"
```

Note: *all* of the above syntax -- all the quotes, braces, brackets, parentheses, etc -- matter to making this run properly and robustly. Don't leave anything out unless you know why it's there, and that leaving it out won't cause trouble.

BTW, if the option (`--flag`) doesn't have to be passed as a separate argument (i.e. if the tool allows `--flag=path/to/folder/a` instead of `--flag path/to/folder/a`), then you can use a substitution to add the `--flag=` bit to each element of the array in a single step:

```
someTool command "${array[@]/#/--flag=}"
```

Explanation: the `/#` means "replace at the beginning (of each element)", then the empty string for the thing to replace, `/` to delimit that from the replacement string, and `--flag=` as the replacement (/addition) string.