# Bash how to add conditional quoted argument '--pull "always"' to docker command

Tags: bash, docker, conditional-statements, arguments, optional-parameters

I am trying to conditionally add arguments to a docker call in a bash script but docker says the flag is unknown, but I can run the command verbatim by hand and it works.

I have tried a few strategies to add the command, including using a string instead of an array, and I have tried using a substitution like the solution here ( using `${array[@]/#/'--pull '}` ): https://stackoverflow.com/a/68675860/10542275

```
 docker run --name application --pull "always" -p 3000:3000 -d private.docker.repository/group/application:version
```

This bash script

```
run() {
  getDockerImageName "/group" "$PROJECT_NAME:$VERSION" "latest";
  local imageName=${imageName};
  local additionalRunParameters=${additionalRunParameters};

  cd "$BASE_PATH/$PROJECT_NAME" || exit 1;

  stopAnyRunning "$PROJECT_NAME";

  echo docker run --name "$PROJECT_NAME" \
    "${additionalRunParameters[@]}" \
    -p 3000:3000 \
    -d "$imageName";

  // docker run --name application --pull "always" -p 3000:3000 -d private.docker.repository/group/application:version

  docker run --name "$PROJECT_NAME" \
    "${additionalRunParameters[@]}" \
    -p 3000:3000 \
    -d "$imageName";

  //unknown flag: --pull "always"
}
```

The helper 'getDockerImageName'

```
# Gets the name of the docker image to use for deploy.
# $1 - The path to the image in the container registry
# $2 - The name of the image and the tag
# $3 - 'latest' if the deploy should use the container built by CI
export imageName="";
export additionalRunParameters=();
getDockerImageName() {
  imageName="group/$2";
  if [[ $3 == "latest" ]]; then
    echo "Using docker image from CI...";
    docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" "https://$DOCKER_BASE_URL";
    imageName="${DOCKER_BASE_URL}${1}/$2";
    additionalRunParameters=('--pull "always"');
  fi
}
```

Comment: I think the option needs to be `--pull=always` or `--pull` `always`, but as two separate words in the latter case and without forcing double quotes to be part of the option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Don't put code (such as arguments) in a variable](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). Basically, use an array is good, and you are *almost* doing that. This line -

```
local additionalRunParameters=${additionalRunParameters};
```

is probably what's causing you trouble, along with

```
additionalRunParameters=('--pull "always"');
```

which is embedding the spaces between what you seem to have *meant* to be two operands (the option and its argument), turning them into a single string that is an unrecognized garble. `//unknown flag: --pull "always"` is telling you the flag it's parsing is `--pull "always"`, which is NOT the `--pull` flag docker DOES know, followed by an argument.

Also,

```
export additionalRunParameters=(); # nope
```

arrays don't really export. Take that out, it will only confuse someone.

A much simplified set of examples:

```
$: declare -f a b c
a ()
{
    foo=('--pull "always"') # single value array
}
b ()
{
    echo "1: \${foo}='${foo}' <= scalar, returns first element of the array";
    echo "2: \"\${foo[@]}\"='${foo[@]}' <= returns entire array (be sure to put in quotes)";
    echo "3: \"\${foo[1]}\"='${foo[1]}' <= indexed, returns only second element of array"
}
c ()
{
    foo=(--pull "always") # two values in this array
}

$: a # sets ${foo[0]} to '--pull "always"'

$: b
1: ${foo}='--pull "always"' <= scalar, returns first element of the array
2: "${foo[@]}"='--pull "always"' <= returns entire array (be sure to put in quotes)
3: "${foo[1]}"='' <= indexed, returns only second element of array

$: c # setd ${foo[0]} to '--pull' and ${foo[1]} to "always"

$: b
1: ${foo}='--pull' <= scalar, returns first element of the array
2: "${foo[@]}"='--pull always' <= returns entire array (be sure to put in quotes)
3: "${foo[1]}"='always' <= indexed, returns only second element of array
```

So what you need is:
getDockerImageName(){
. . . # stuff
additionalRunParameters=( --pull "always" ); # no single quotes
}

and just take OUT

```
local additionalRunParameters=${additionalRunParameters}; # it's global, no need
```

You have one more issue though - `"${additionalRunParameters[@]}" \` is good, *as long as the array isn't empty.* In your example it will apparently always be loaded with the same values, so I don't see why you are adding all this extra complication of putting it into a *global* array that gets loaded incidentally in another function... seems like an antipattern. Just put the arguments you are universally enforcing anyway on the command itself.

*However*, on the possibility that you simplified some details out, then if this array is ever empty it's going to pass a literal quoted empty string as an argument on the command line, and you're likely to get something like the following error:

```
$: docker run --name foo "" -p 3000:3000 -d bar # docker doesn't understand the empty string
docker: invalid reference format.
```

Maybe, rather than

```
additionalRunParameters=( --pull "always" ); # no single quotes
```

and

```
"${additionalRunParameters[@]}" \
```

what you really want is

```
pull_always=true
```

and

```
${pull_always:+ --pull always } \
```

...with no quotes, so that if the var has been set (with anything) it evaluates to the desired result, but if it's unset *and unquoted* it evaluates to nothing and gets ignored, as nothing actually gets passed in - not even a null string.

Good luck. Let us know if you need more help.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the thorough and well explained answer!  I get exactly what you are saying and it makes sense now!  The solution using a boolean to conditionally append the flag worked perfect.

There was a decent amount of simplification done for the example, as this is part of a set of scripts i have been working on to handle several different projects and configurations.

The local/export were just there because the helper is actually imported from another script and the IDE didn't like that, but it works without so Thank you for pointing that out!